# Is this call a conveyor or an escalator in a supermarket?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

[image]

**Is this call a conveyor or an escalator in a supermarket?**

If it is called an escalator, then there are 2 opposite escalators: one moves down and the other moves up.

**Which of these are correct expressions?**

*-go up/ down the escalator*

*-ride up/ down the escalator*

*-ride the up / down escalator*

*-ride up/ down by escalator*

*-go up/ down by escalator*

*-take up/ down the escalator*

*-take the escalator up/ down*

Comment: Usually just ***go*** - but you might use ***ride*** when talking to a child, or ***take*** when giving instructions to someone about how to get to some section above the ground floor in a large indoor space like this. We wouldn't normally use a preposition (typically ***on***) with ***go***, and you *can't* use one with ***take***, but it's just a stylistic choice whether to include it in ***ride [on] the escalator***.

Comment: These are sometimes called "travelators", as distinct from escalators which have actual steps.

Comment: Also known as moving walkway.

Comment: The name of the 1959 moving walkway at the Bank London Underground station was written 'Trav-O-Lator', which is, apparently a registered brand of the Otis company.

Comment: It's an inclined slidewalk.

Comment: @Davo And an ink-lined plane is a stamp pad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both would be understood, especially in context.  However in my local supermarket it is called a conveyor.  There is an recording that repeats "Please prepare to push the trolley off the end of the conveyor" https://youtu.be/CzzdTno2KA8?t=35

You can go up on the conveyor.  You can take (or ride) the conveyor (up to the first floor).  You can't push your trolley up the conveyor, but only because there is a locking mechanism that applies the brakes. But if you are walking you can walk up the conveyor. When you near the end of they conveyor, the brakes are automatically disengaged, which is why you need to be prepared to push your trolley off the end of the conveyor.  But don't try walking up the down conveyor, it's dangerous and you will be removed by security.

Comment: But I just stand still and  I don't have to move my legs when I am on the conveyor as it carries me up/down, Do we still say "**I go up/down on the conveyor**"?

Comment: Tom, look at the second paragraph.  I explain how you have to stand still, if you have a trolley, but you still say "go up on the conveyor".  . . "You can go up on the conveyor. You can take (or ride) the conveyor (up to the first floor). You can't push your trolley up the conveyor, but only because there is a locking mechanism"